# не обновляет приложение ClickOnce

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

Пытаюсь обновить приложение через ClickOnce.
Приложу скрины настройки программы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я делаю новую версию публикации и перезахожу в приложение оно не обновляет его автоматически почему-то, а нужно с ftp-сервера (куда я публикую) выкачивать папку и через апликейшен обновлять. В чем прикол, не пойму

Comment: я ничего не понял. У вас приложение лежит на ftp? Вы положили туда новую версию, а клиенты не обновились?

Comment: @tym32167 сама папка с приложением лежит на диске D, публикацию я делаю на ftp сервер. Установил приложение, пытаюсь обновить, но версия не меняется. Обновляет только если с публикации выкачать апликейшен файл и через него обновляет. Но это не правильно, я так понимаю уже установленная программа при запуске должна проверять на обновление и при необходимости обновляться автоматически

Comment: понятия не имею, что тут написано, я посто загуглил. [Если приложение будет устанавливаться из Интернета, выберите параметр С веб-сайта и введите URL-адрес в соответствии с тем путем к файлу, который вы указали на предыдущем этапе. Нажмите кнопку Далее. (Данный параметр обычно используется, когда в качестве расположения публикации указывается FTP-адрес. Загрузка из FTP напрямую не поддерживается, поэтому URL-адрес необходимо ввести здесь вручную.)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @tym32167 вся соль в том, что делаю все один в один по настройке публикации. Но не обновляет( не пойму почему

Comment: Потому что у вас линки с которых должны происходить установка и обновление - это сетевая папка (smb). Если она же является корнем ftp, то работать должно, но только на вашей машине или в вашей сети, если папка доступна на чтение другим. В противном случае нужно прикрутить простенький вебсервер и сайт, корень которого будет совпадать с корнем ftp, а в настройках публикации указать этот сайт в качестве источника установки и обновления.